# Getting a popup box to display in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a tutorial of a box that displays in the vertical middle of the screen a swell as the horizontal middle of the screen.

My current try has lots of failing when the vertical screen size small.

It also needs to be responsive. Can any one point to a tutorial or snippet with a solution.

```
    function openPopUp( item ) {
    var render_height = $('body').height();
    $('.black_overlay').height(render_height + 'px');
    $('.black_overlay').show();
    $('#popup').show();
    var html ='';
    html += '<h6 class="popup-header">More Information About the Debt</h6>';
    html += '<img src="images/cancel30.png" width="20" height="20" onclick="closePopUp();" style="display:block;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;cursor:pointer;">'; 
    html += '<table style="width:100%;">';
    html += '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>' + $(item).attr("hidden-data-dfname") + "</td><tr>";
    html += '<tr><td>Last Name</td><td>' + $(item).attr("hidden-data-dlname") + "</td><tr>";
    html += '</table>';
    $('#popup').html(html);
} // end method openPopUp


function closePopUp() {
    $('#popup').hide();
    $('.black_overlay').hide();
} // end function closePopUp


    <div id="popup">
    </div>  
      <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>

    .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
#popup {
   position: fixed;
   display: none;
   top: 25%;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px solid #CCC;
   background-color: #F9F9F9;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   width: calc(100% - 42px);
   z-index: 1002;
}
#popup table {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.popup-header {
    padding:5px;
    background:#006;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use only this much css for horizontal and vertical centering of `div`

```
#popup {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

No JavaScript and no `calc` etc. And it will remain in the center whatever screen size may be.

Comment: That works on a large screen but once the screen width get smaller it moves down the page until its off the view port. In my description I said that i wanted it to be in the middle of the window but its possible a better word is a view port. With this css its not visible at all on my phone.

Comment: @DaleSnowdon some other css might be overriding this on smaller resolutions, (bootstrap??), might be `margin-top` or something like that will be causing the issue on smaller screen width..

Answer (score 1):

I solved using https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

You have a div containing your modal content:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="terms-of-use-modal"... your dialog html here
```

Then a function that initializes the modal with responsive dimensions:

```
function init_dialog(){
  var modal_width = $(window).width() - ($(window).width() / 3);
  var modal_height = $(window).height() - 50;

  $("#terms-of-use-modal").dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: modal_width,
    maxHeight: modal_height,
    dialogClass: 'terms-of-use-dialog',
    buttons: {
      Ok: function(){
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And that link is clicked the modal will appear:

```
$("#terms-of-use-link").on("click", function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  init_dialog();
});
```

You can also use init_dialog function anytime you want modal visible.
You can add css settings like:

```
#terms-of-use-modal { ... }
```